# Indent error is being triggered and I cannot find a solution

Tags: python, while-loop, indentation

Code:

```
def funt():
  print(Fore.GREEN, end='')
  tool = input('Enter Desired Tool: ')
  if tool == 'web':
      try:
        print(Fore.CYAN, end='')
        site = input('Please Enter The Website Here: ')
        response = requests.get(site)
        requests.get(site)
        if response.status_code == 200:
          print(f'{Fore.GREEN}Online!')
          sleep(1)
        else:
          print(f'{Fore.RED}Offline!')
          sleep(1)

while True:
    funt()
```

Location of Error is `while True:` . 
The Error Is As Follows:

```
    while True:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected unindent
```

I cannot find a solution, there is not any sign of indentation in the while loop.

Comment: Where's the `except` in your `try/except` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`try` expects an `except` block followed by it.

You can modify your code as follows:

```py
def funt():
  print(Fore.GREEN, end='')
  tool = input('Enter Desired Tool: ')
  if tool == 'web':
      try:
        print(Fore.CYAN, end='')
        site = input('Please Enter The Website Here: ')
        response = requests.get(site)
        requests.get(site)
        if response.status_code == 200:
          print(f'{Fore.GREEN}Online!')
          sleep(1)
        else:
          print(f'{Fore.RED}Offline!')
          sleep(1)
      except:
        pass

while True:
    funt()
```

But writing proper code requires you to handle exceptions. So, if possible write a piece of code in the `except` block.

Comment: More exactly is expects an `except` or `finally` block.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
def funt():
  print(Fore.GREEN, end='')
  tool = input('Enter Desired Tool: ')
  if tool == 'web':
      try:
        print(Fore.CYAN, end='')
        site = input('Please Enter The Website Here: ')
        response = requests.get(site)
        requests.get(site)
        if response.status_code == 200:
          print(f'{Fore.GREEN}Online!')
          sleep(1)
        else:
          print(f'{Fore.RED}Offline!')
          sleep(1)
      # You were missing this part:
      except:
        print("Message") 

while True:
   funt()
```

A `try` block always goes together with a `catch` block. The purpose of the try block is to attempt to run code that may `throw` an `exception`. The `catch` block is what catches this exception.

Answer (score 0):

You've missed `except` block for your `try` block

[Here's](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) some info on exception handling in python.